# How can I run a windows VM on an machine running Ubuntu that I have remote access to?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, windows-10, kvm-virtualization

The situation is that I have remote access to a machine running Ubuntu 20.04.5. This is brand new with nothing setup.

I want to setup a windows VM on this remote machine, and ideally have some client running on my local machine (my macbook) that can then directly connect to the Windows instance without having to go through the linux system manually every time, and can give me GUI access.

Currently I am completely clueless about how I should proceed. Any direction/help is appreciated.

Comment: If your system is 20.04.5 as stated; I suggest you apply security fixes & package upgrades asap if the machine is accessible online, as you're behind on applying security fixes. A 20.04 system if updated will currently report itself as 20.04.6; you can refer to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ for the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded week+ before that date.